# Authentication Failure When Connecting to MySQL as Non-Root User

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

My login attempts fail for a new user account that I have created, and I have spent several hours learning how authentication is handled by MySQL, but ultimately I think I'm just not fully understanding how all the components fit together regarding MySQL Server's authentication logic.

**All on the same server:**

- MySQL 5.7
- phpMyAdmin 4.9
- Ubuntu 18.04

**Additional info:**

- There are no users with blank usernames in the table mysql.user
- The password doesn't have special characters
- I've tried localhost, 127.0.0.1 and the actual hostname itself
- /var/log/mysql/error.log only shows the exact same error message

**CREATING THE USER**

This is done by either:

1. phpMyAdmin GUI > SQL tab:

```
flush privileges;
create user 'testuser'@'localhost' identified by 'password!';
grant * on inventory to 'testuser'@'localhost';
flush privileges;
```

2. phpMyAdmin GUI > User Account tab > Add User Account
3. ssh into the Ubuntu server and create the user from the mysql command line (as root)

Regardless of how I do it, I can create the user successfully, but I'm unable to authenticate.

**AUTHENTICATING THE USER**

Here's the two ways I've tried:

1) From an ssh session on the Ubuntu server:

- mysql -u testuser -p
- mysql -u testuser - h 127.0.0.1 -p
- mysql -u testuser - h localhost -p
- mysql -u testuser - h  -p

2) Run connect.php from another machine using (IE / Chrome / FF):

```
<?php

$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='testuser';
$dbpass='password';
$dbname='inventory';

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error: Couldn't connect: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

?>
```

2) 
Depending on whether I used `'testuser'@'%'` or `'testuser'@'localhost'` I'll get one of two errors:

- Access denied for user 'testuser'@'%' (using password: YES)
- Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

To rule out this being a permissions issue, I assigned the user all global permissions, but the error message didn't change, so I reverted the change.

Running `select host,user,plugin,authentication_string,account_locked from mysql.user where user='testuser';` shows:

**host** localhost

**user** testuser

**plugin** mysql_native_password

**authentication_string** blahblahblah

**account_locked** N

Comment: Access denied means your username or password is incorrect.

Comment: If the php script runs on a remote machine and you provide localhost as dbhost, then you are connecting to the mysql on the computer where the php script runs. That could explain the access denied. That ssh session is also suspicious to me, I don't think you are connecting to the mysql server you think you do.

Comment: @Shadow it was the wrong server. I think you can only get fired from your job three times in a week, so I'm not that far over the limit. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you delete this question

Answer (score 1):

Try granting permissions like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON inventory.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost';
```